# WordPress - WP Super Cache Unable to write on wp-config

Tags: wordpress, centos7, vps

After changing all the WordPress permissions to 777 and assigning them to group of apache:apache still Wp Super Cache plugin can't change the wp-config.php

I don't know why!

My server is :

CentOS 7

PHP 71

Apache

MariaDB

Apache Error Log:

```
[Thu Nov 02 02:01:45.637165 2017] [php7:warn] [pid 17633] [client 5.202.27.148:25292] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cachewp-cache-base.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 72, referer: http://website.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=10821&action=edit
```

Wordpress Error:

```
Warning! You must set WP_CACHE and WPCACHEHOME in your wp-config.php for this plugin to work correctly: define( 'WP_CACHE', true ); 
define( 'WPCACHEHOME', '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache' );
```

Comment: As far as i know apache uses `www-data:www-data` for it's user & group

Comment: do `sudo chown www-data:www-data . -R` on wordpress root.

Comment: @TouqeerShafi if it is installed on Ubuntu, On CentOS it is apache

Comment: you're right i thought that it's www-data for centos as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved by disabling SELinux that prevents apache user from editing files and folder.

Comment: Don't leave `wp-config` as 777. This is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Yes absolutely, i change it to 755

Comment: 755 is still not enough. At 755 database credentials are still exposed.

Comment: It's good practice to set wp-config to 6-6-0 or 660. This means the file owner and their group can read and write to `wp-config` but nobody else can.

Answer (score 0):

This is right. wp-config should be writeble only by user manually. This file should not be writable using code.  Please put these configuration manually in your wp-config.php.

Comment: I believe that Plugins like WP Super Cache can do this automatically but there is something with my VPS ...

Comment: chnage the file permission to 755

Comment: @RajkumarGour setting `wp-config` to 755 exposes database credentials.